# Uncover Lenny Fingers' street hustle

Tags: wordplay, graph-theory, river-crossing

Lenny Fingers is out on the street again, hustling people with his shell games.  This time, he's using words.

As you walk by, Lenny grabs you with an enthusiastic smile and shows you two words side-by-side, betting that he can switch their positions with just a few swipes.  It seems impossible, but Lenny has long, crazy fingers and he's quick and he talks nonstop.  Distracted by all the patter, you don't realize that he is able to hide multiple letters under his fingertips.  This allows him to transfer 2, 3, or 4 letters at a time from one word to the other.

We took some covert video and played it back in slow motion.  Watch carefully:

```
 TESTS            RAINING
   |            .   |
   |          .     |
   |      I,N,G     |
   |      .         |
   v    .           v
TESTINGS          RAIN
   |    .           |
   |      .         |
   |      T,E,T,G   |
   |          .     |
   v            .   v
 SINS             TREATING
   |            .   |
   |          .     |
   |      T,A,T,G   |
   |      .         |
   v    .           v
TASTINGS          REIN
   |    .           |
   |      .         |
   |      T,A,S     |
   |          .     |
   v            .   v
 STING            RETAINS
   |            .   |
   |          .     |
   |      R,E,I,S   |
   |      .         |
   v    .           v
RESISTING          TAN
   |    .           |
   |      .         |
   |      S,T,I,G   |
   |          .     |
   v            .   v
 RESIN            STATING
   |            .   |
   |          .     |
   |      T,A,T,G   |
   |      .         |
   v    .           v
RESTATING          SIN
   |    .           |
   |      .         |
   |       R,E      |
   |          .     |
   v            .   v
STATING           RESIN
   |    .           |
   |      .         |
   |      S,T,I,G   |
   |          .     |
   v            .   v
  TAN             RESISTING
   |            .   |
   |          .     |
   |      R,E,I,S   |
   |      .         |
   v    .           v
RETAINS           STING
   |    .           |
   |      .         |
   |      T,A,S     |
   |          .     |
   v            .   v
 REIN             TASTINGS
   |            .   |
   |          .     |
   |      T,A,T,G   |
   |      .         |
   v    .           v
TREATING          SINS
   |    .           |
   |      .         |
   |      T,E,T,G   |
   |          .     |
   v            .   v
 RAIN             TESTINGS
   |            .   |
   |          .     |
   |      I,N,G     |
   |      .         |
   v    .           v
RAINING           TESTS
```

Observations:
1.  At each step, Lenny transfers 2, 3, or 4 letters from one word to the other.  Each side remains a valid English word after extraction and insertion of the letters.
2.  The letters can be extracted from anywhere in the word, and they can be inserted anywhere in the other word.  They need not be contiguous.
3.  The spacing of the letters does not need to be maintained since Lenny can easily adjust the spacing of his fingers.  However, the **ordering** of letters must be maintained because Lenny can't change the ordering of his fingers.
4.  The direction of movement does not need to alternate between right to left and left to right.  At each step, Lenny can swipe in either direction.  (See the eighth and ninth step above, for example.)

Now that you know how it's done, see if you can figure out his latest scam:

Lenny changes

```
    TRACED           REHEAT
```

into

```
    REHEAT           TRACED
```

BTW, as long as it doesn't involve money, Lenny is a pretty easy-going guy.  He doesn't care about American and British spellings (THEATER or THEATRE) and allows words like HEARTED with [old](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hearted) and [new](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hearted) meanings.

---

Here is an even more lowbrow solution than the ones found by @GarethMcCaughan:

> `TRACED          REHEAT`
>   `RETRACED        HEAT`
>   `TRACE           HEARTED`
>   `TERRACED        HATE`
>   `RACED           THEATER`
>   `RATCHETED       EAR`
>   `RATED           CHEATER`
>   `CRATERED        HEAT`
>   `CATER           HEARTED`
>   `CHARTERED       EAT`
>   `HATER           CREATED`
>   `CHEATER         RATED`
>   `EAR             RATCHETED`
>   `THEATER         RACED`
>   `HATE            TERRACED`
>   `HEARTED         TRACE`
>   `HEAT            RETRACED`
>   `REHEAT          TRACED`

Comment: Did you want the no-computers tag on this?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan – Please feel free to use computers.  This is a tough one, so you might need all the help you can get!  (Although I believe that the humans, if they use the hints I gave, might still have a slight edge over the computers.)

Comment: I find it extremely easy to miss possible moves when looking by eye.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan – This puzzle gives me a sinister delight for exactly that reason — it's just too unintuitive, even for a single step.  I'm hoping there's someone out there who has unhuman intuition who can take out a pencil and paper and just solve it like a breeze!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confession: the following is all found using computer help. (I did at least write the code to do it.) Further confession: earlier versions of this answer included a bunch of not-very-satisfactory solutions using very obscure words; you can find them in the edit history if you care.

Unsurprisingly, one can do this more quickly if one allows rarer words. Thus:

> traced **re**heat -> **re**traced heat
>  **re**trace**d** heat -> trace hea**r**t**ed**
>  trace **hea**r**t**ed -> trac**heat**e red
>  **t**rache**ate** red -> rache **t**re**ate**d
>  r**ach**e treated -> re tr**ach**eated
>  re trac**heat**ed -> re**heat** traced

but I at least was not familiar with

> RACHE, a kind of hunting dog.

More acceptable:

> traced **re**heat -> **re**traced heat
>  **re**traced heat -> traced he**re**at
>  traced h**er**eat -> t**er**raced heat
>  **ter**raced heat -> raced **t**h**er**eat
>  raced **th**er**e**a**t** -> ra**t**c**het**ed era
>  **r**a**t**ch**et**ed era -> ached **r**e**t**r**e**a**t**
>  ached **re**treat -> **re**ached treat
>  reach**ed** treat -> reach treat**ed**
>  re**ach** treated -> re tr**ach**eated
>  re trac**heat**ed -> re**heat** traced

Simpler still but longer (and I regret that I've been too lazy to mark it up with exactly what letters are being shifted each way, this time):

> traced reheat
>  retraced heat
>  traced hereat
>  terraced heat
>  raced thereat
>  ratcheted era
>  ached retreat
>  reached treat
>  reach treated
>  reteach rated
>  teach rerated
>  teacher rated
>  ear ratcheted
>  theater raced
>  hate terraced
>  hearted trace
>  heat retraced
>  reheat traced

Comment: Gareth, there must be something missing from your word list.  We have confirmatory [evidence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85969/chrysanthemum-bejeweled-with-dew-drops) of that.  ;-)

Comment: There is a solution to this puzzle which uses only the most common words, if you can accept HEARTED.

Comment: @SlowMagic I think you may be commenting on an old version of my answer; the one here now uses only words that I think are no rarer than HEARTED.

Comment: No, I am seeing your latest solution...  And I will admit that there are at least three words which are making me ashamed of my public school education.

Comment: OK, then take a look at the latest addition which is a little lower-brow.